# JSON file can't be modified

Tags: node.js, json, fs

I am currently creating a web that uses a variable that I can store in a JSON format. My plan is to modify the value of the JSON every time there's a connection to a certain route. The problem is it just won't write.

I have tried to use fs.writeFile and fs.writeFileSync but none of them seem to work.

```
// Code I Have tried
const kwitansi = require('./no_kwitansi.json')

app.get('', async (req, res) => {
    kwitansi.no_kwitansi += await 1
    await fs.writeFile('../no_kwitansi.json', JSON.stringify(kwitansi, null, 2), function (e) {
        if (e) {
            throw new Error
        } else {
            console.log('Wrote to file')
        }
    })
    await console.log(kwitansi)
    await res.send(kwitansi)
})

// An Example of my JSON File
{
    "no_kwitansi":4
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write to a place where you do not have permission. Note that you opened `./no_kwitansi.json`, but you are trying to write to `../no_kwitansi.json` (one directory back). If you are sure you can replace the original file, remove the extra `.` in the write line.

If the error persists, you also need to be sure that you have the proper permissions to write the file. If you are using *nix or mac, you can check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions).